# Realtime database update or create functionality

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I have a user object in firebases realtime database. I am querying realtime database and when successful I am wanting to write some new data to the user object under the users node.

***My desired outcome:*** When a user has not fetched the information before, a new field called 'lastViewed' under the user object is created and if the field has already been created then we update the timeViewed keys value. A user can have multiple objects in the array corresponding to the uuid of the fetched data.

*Please see the user object below*

This may not need to be an array if using .push()

```
-N0X8VLHTw3xgvD2vJs- : { // this is the users unique key
    name: 'myName',
    lastViewed: {
     [
      {
       timeViewed: 1651558791, // this is the field to update if exists
       datasUniqueKey: 'N17ZmwIsbqaVSGh93Q0' // if this value exists update timeViewed else we create the entry.
      },
      {
       timeViewed: 1651558952,
       datasUniqueKey: 'N17ZmwIsbqaVSad3gad'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

*Please see my attempt below.*

```
const getData = database()
  .ref(`data/${uniqueKeyFromData}`)
  .on('value', snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
          database()
              .ref(`users/${currentFirebaseUserKey}/lastViewed`) // currentFirebaseUserKey = N0X8VLHTw3xgvD2vJs
              .once('value', childSnapshot => {
                  if (childSnapshot.exists()) {
                      // update
                      database()
                          .ref(
                              `users/${currentFirebaseUserKey}/lastViewed`,
                          )
                          .update({
                              timeViewed: new Date(), // new data will not give us the corresponding date format in the user object above but don't worry about that
                              fetchedDatasUniqueKey: uniqueKeyFromData,
                          });
                  } else {
                      // create
                      database()
                          .ref(
                              `users/${currentFirebaseUserKey}/lastViewed`,
                          )
     // Push creates a unique key which might not be required so maybe set?
                          .push({
                              timeViewed: new Date(),
                              fetchedDatasUniqueKey: uniqueKeyFromData,
                          });
                  }
              });
      }
  });
```

*Where I think I am going wrong*

Above I am not creating an array, if I use push I would get a unique key generated from firebase but then would have to use that key when updating, something like

```
`users/${currentFirebaseUserKey}/lastViewed/${lastViewedUniqueKey}`
```

So the user object would look like so

```
-N0X8VLHTw3xgvD2vJs- : { // this is the users unique key
    name: 'myName',
    lastViewed: {
      -N17i2X2-rKYXywbJGmQ: { // this is lastViewedUniqueKey
         timeViewed: 1651558791,
         datasUniqueKey: 'N17ZmwIsbqaVSGh93Q0' 
      },
  }
}
```

then check for snapshot.key in the if?, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want a list of data, but a single set of properties for ``, you should just call `set` instead of `push`:

```
database()
    .ref(`users/${currentFirebaseUserKey}/lastViewed`)
    .set({ // 
        timeViewed: new Date(),
        fetchedDatasUniqueKey: uniqueKeyFromData,
    });
```

I also don't think you need the two different cases here for create vs update, as both seem to do the exact same thing. If you *do* need both cases though, consider [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: I think I may have explained poorly, I am looking for a list, so everytime a user renders data with a different uuid it would add it to the list under the user object or update it

Like so:

`lastViewed: {
     [
      {
       timeViewed: 1651558791, // this is the field to update if the below exists
       datasUniqueKey: 'N17ZmwIsbqaVSGh93Q0'
      },
      {
       timeViewed: 1651558952,
       datasUniqueKey: 'N17ZmwIsbqaVSad3gad' // since this different its a new object with a new times viewed
      },
    ]`

 Apologies for the formatting of the above object